# How to break the sequence when an item from the list is found?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, foreach, iteration

My list contains multiple properties like Make, Model and Color and many other and one string which contains the concat version of those three mentions above. For Example string contains "Maruti Suzuki Desire White" in which "Maruti" is make, "Suzuki Desire" is model and "White" is color and in the list there many makes,models and colors to find the exact match. Here is my sample code below

Here is the sample Model:

```
public class MakeModelColor()
{
  public string Make {get; set;}
  public string Model {get; set;}
  public string Color {get; set;}
}
```

> Here is a sample Code:

```
string concatedString = "Maruti Suzuki Desire White"
MakeModelColor model = new MakeModelColor();
IList<MakeModelColor> list=  new List<MakeModelColor>();
list = GetMakeModelColor();
```

variable `list` contains all model, make and color stored in database.

```
foreach (var itemMake in list)
{
  if(concatedString.Contains(itemMake.Make)) 
    model.Make = itemMake.Make;
}

foreach (var itemModel in list)
{
  if(concatedString.Contains(itemModel.Model)) 
    model.Model = itemModel.Model;
}

foreach (var itemColor in list)
{
  if(concatedString.Contains(itemColor.Color)) 
    model.Color = itemColor.Color;
}
```

Above is just a sample code for clarifying my question. In addition to that, I wanted to break the loop if any condition satisfies and stop the iteration immeditately.
I don't know whether I'm able to explain the question correctly but hope you'll understand and if there is a better option than foreach, please state that too.

Comment: you can use `break;` inside if condition

Answer (score 3):

Use [`break;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) in each of your cycles.

Answer (score 1):

You have not only a problem with how to exit the loop. (That's easy, just read some basic book on the language) but you have also a problem with looping three times on the same list just to check different parts of your class data. A better approach should be the one that removes the three loops

```
MakeModelColor model = null;
foreach (var element in list)
{
    if(element.ToString() == concatedString)
    {
        model = element;
        break; // <= here break the loop and exit
    }
}
if(model != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + model.ToString());
}
```

To make it work you need to add an override for ToString() into your class and return the string representation of the instance

```
public class MakeModelColor()
{
  public string Make {get; set;}
  public string Model {get; set;}
  public string Color {get; set;}
  public override string ToString()
  {
     return $"{this.Make} {this.Model} {this.Color}";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not wish to use a break, you can change to a the foreach loops that you have into for loops and add the break condition to something like the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count && model.Make == null; i++)
{
  if(concatedString.Contains(itemMake.Make)) 
     model.Make = itemMake.Make;
}
```